# How to read properties file

Tags: java, maven, properties

In any `maven` project, How we can read "`.properties`" file.
Is it possible to use annotation to read without `spring` project.
I would like to read using `annotation` only but don't want to use `spring` dependencies.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with _maven_? AFAIU you'd like to assign property values to variables via annotations – at runtime. That's nothing Maven can achieve since it is used at compile/build time.

Comment: Is it just Spring you don't want to use or none of its alternatives, as well?

Comment: Maven, I have maven java project and looking for some dependencies but not springs.